# Sumar las columnas de una tabla HTML con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una tabla obtenida desde la base de datos la cual estoy intentando sumar las columnas en  Total. muestro la imagen para que se pueda entender:[image: Tabla kardex]

Codigo html

```
<table id="tblKardexValorizado" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="encabezado">
                        <th>Sucursal</th>
                        <th>Articulo</th>
                        <th>Categoria</th>
                        <th>Unidad</th>
                        <th>Total de Ingresos</th>
                        <th>Valor de Ingresos</th>
                        <th>Total de Stock</th>
                        <th>Valor de Stock</th>
                        <th>Total de Ventas</th>
                        <th>Valor de Ventas</th>
                        <th>Utilidad Valorizada</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tfoot>
                    <tr class="total">
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Total </th>
                        <th>Total </th>
                        <th>Total </th>
                        <th>Total </th>
                        <th>Total </th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                        <th>Total</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>

            </table>
```

Comment: pues no me funciona amigos tal vez soy un novato aun pero igual me aparece los datos de la tabla pero no realiza la sumatoria de numero solo me dice 0 o NaN

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando `jQuery` tendrías que utilizar [each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) y [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Por ejemplo;

```js
//Ejecuto la función al cargar la página
$(document).ready(function()
{
  //Defino los totales de mis 2 columnas en 0
  var total_col1 = 0;
  var total_col2 = 0;
  //Recorro todos los tr ubicados en el tbody
  $('#ejemplo tbody').find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
             
        //Voy incrementando las variables segun la fila ( .eq(0) representa la fila 1 )     
        total_col1 += parseFloat($(this).find('td').eq(0).text());
        total_col2 += parseFloat($(this).find('td').eq(1).text());
                
    });
    //Muestro el resultado en el th correspondiente a la columna
    $('#ejemplo tfoot tr th').eq(0).text("Total " + total_col1);
    $('#ejemplo tfoot tr th').eq(1).text("Total " + total_col2);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="ejemplo" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr class="encabezado">
            <th>Campo 1</th>
            <th>Campo 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Espero que sea lo que necesitabas! Saludos

Comment: Agradezco su repuesta y su tiempo, al parecer no entendió lo que pretendo es sumar  el contenido de la columna, ejemplo de la imagen total de stock 1 +1 en total me tiene que arrojar al suma total: 2

Comment: Osea que tendrías que sumar dos columnas y ubicar el resultado de la suma en una tercer columna?

Comment: O te referís a sumarlo y ubicarlo en el tfoot?

Comment: exacto en tfoot.

Comment: @Hakim ahí modifiqué la respuesta para que cumpla con lo que buscas!

Comment: Agradecerlo una vez mas, es exacto lo que necesito pero como seria sin botón, una vez que se carga la tabla me tiene que mostrar la suma automáticamente.

Comment: @Hakim Ahí lo modifique para que lo haga automáticamente, te recomiendo que busques como funciona $(document), te va a ayudar para mas adelante!

Comment: Gracias, saludos me fui de util

Comment: Si esta fue la solución a tu pregunta, te pediría que la marques como correcta para que se de como respondida, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con este Script, donde `i=5` representa el número de la columna donde empieza a sumar y 11 la columna final que se desea sumar.

```js
for(i=5;i<=11;i++)
{
  var total=0;
  $('table#tblKardexValorizado tbody td:nth-child(' + i + ')').each(function (index) 
  {
    total += parseFloat($(this).text());  
  });
  $('table#tblKardexValorizado tfoot th:nth-child(' + i + ')').text("Total: " + total)  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tblKardexValorizado" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr class="encabezado">
            <th>Sucursal</th>
            <th>Articulo</th>
            <th>Categoria</th>
            <th>Unidad</th>
            <th>Total de Ingresos</th>
            <th>Valor de Ingresos</th>
            <th>Total de Stock</th>
            <th>Valor de Stock</th>
            <th>Total de Ventas</th>
            <th>Valor de Ventas</th>
            <th>Utilidad Valorizada</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>asdasdasd</td>
        <td>asdasdasd</td>
        <td>asdasdasd</td>
        <td>asdasdasd</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>asdasdasd</td>
        <td>asdasdasd</td>
        <td>asdasdasd</td>
        <td>asdasdasd</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="total">
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th>Total </th>
            <th>Total </th>
            <th>Total </th>
            <th>Total </th>
            <th>Total </th>
            <th>Total</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Weimar Yamit Moreno**  gracias por la respuesta es exacto lo que necesito, pero en este caso las filas son obtenidas desde la consulta de base de datos por eso no se puede sumar con la función mencionada.

[image: tabla obtenida de db]

```js
for(i=5;i<=11;i++)
{
  var total=0;
  $('table#tblKardexValorizado tbody td:nth-child(' + i + ')').each(function (index) 
  {
    total += parseFloat($(this).text());  
  });
  $('table#tblKardexValorizado tfoot th:nth-child(' + i + ')').text("Total: " + total)  
}
```

```html
 <table id="tblKardexValorizado" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="encabezado">
                            <th>Sucursal</th>
                            <th>Articulo</th>
                            <th>Categoria</th>
                            <th>Unidad</th>
                            <th>Total de Ingresos</th>
                            <th>Valor de Ingresos</th>
                            <th>Total de Stock</th>
                            <th>Valor de Stock</th>
                            <th>Total de Ventas</th>
                            <th>Valor de Ventas</th>
                            <th>Utilidad Valorizada</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
             
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr class="total">
                         <th>Total</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>Total </th>
                            <th>Total </th>
                            <th>Total </th>
                            <th>Total </th>
                            <th>Total </th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                            <th>Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>

                </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

funciona para listar tabla de base de datos en java scrip

```
function ListadoKardexValorizado(){ 
    var idsucursal = $("#txtIdSucursal").val();
var tabla = $('#tblKardexValorizado').dataTable(
    {   "aProcessing": true,
        "aServerSide": true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copyHtml5',
            'excelHtml5',
            'csvHtml5',
            'pdfHtml5'
        ],
        "aoColumns":[                   
                {   "mDataProp": "0"},
                {   "mDataProp": "1"},
                {   "mDataProp": "2"},
                {   "mDataProp": "3"},
                {   "mDataProp": "4"},
                {   "mDataProp": "5"},
                {   "mDataProp": "6"},
                {   "mDataProp": "7"},
                {   "mDataProp": "8"},
                {   "mDataProp": "9"},
                {   "mDataProp": "10"},

        ],"ajax": 
            {
                url: './ajax/ConsultasComprasAjax.php?op=listKardexValorizado',
                type : "get",
                data:{idsucursal: idsucursal},
                dataType : "json",

                error: function(e){
                    console.log(e.responseText);    
                }
            },
        "bDestroy": true

    }).DataTable();

};
```